# Do I need to regenerate model every time I use different machine in MVC Entity Framework..?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have svn repo of project on server from which I used to check out project on my machine and does work.

My Project uses MVC 3 and Entity Framework. When I checkout project then I have to delete models and regenerate model i.e .edmx files) and update web.config file.

This process is very time consuming and I dont like Is there any work around on it..?

Here is my connection string

```
 <connectionStrings>

        <add name="AppConfigDBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.AppConfigModel.csdl|res://*/Models.AppConfigModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.AppConfigModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=INMHVIHWD025\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=test_db_name;persist security info=True;user id=admin;password=admin;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />

           ...
           ...
           ...

      </connectionStrings>
```

I get below error if I don't regenerate models

```
    2018-11-06 16:27:47,080 [5] INFO  MyApp.Controllers.homeController [(null)] - User Logout Successfully...!
    2018-11-06 16:27:47,131 [6] INFO  MyApp.Controllers.homeController [(null)] - Inside homecontroller Index () 
    2018-11-06 16:27:53,015 [5] INFO  MyApp.Controllers.homeController [(null)] - Inside homecontroller Index () 
    2018-11-06 16:28:08,722 [5] INFO  MyApp.Controllers.homeController [(null)] - Inside homecontroller Login Post () 
    2018-11-06 16:28:23,733 [5] ERROR MyApp.Controllers.homeController [(null)] - Exception inside Login () :   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.OpenStoreConnectionIf(Boolean openCondition, DbConnection storeConnectionToOpen, DbConnection originalConnection, String exceptionCode, String attemptedOperation, Boolean& closeStoreConnectionOnFailure)
       at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()
       at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection()
       at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
       at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
       at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.<>c__11`1.<GetElementFunction>b__11_1(IEnumerable`1 sequence)
       at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.ExecuteSingle[TResult](IEnumerable`1 query, Expression queryRoot)
       at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[S](Expression expression)
       at System.Linq.Queryable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate)
       at MyApp.Controllers.homeController.Login(FormCollection form) in C:\Visual Studio 2017 Workspace\Project1\MyApp\Controllers\homeController.cs:line 116
    2018-11-06 16:28:23,738 [6] INFO  MyApp.Controllers.homeController [(null)] - Inside homecontroller Index ()
```

And below is my controller code.

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Login(FormCollection form)
        {
            log.Info("Inside homecontroller Login Post () ");
            string uname = form["uname"];
            string password = form["password"];
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(uname) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(password)) {
                TempData["errorMsg"] = "Username or password required..!";
                log.Info("Username or password required..!");
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            try
            {           
                    string encryptedPwd = MyApp.Utils.PasswordUtils.Encrypt(password);
                    var myUser = userProfileDBObj.tbl_user_profile.FirstOrDefault(u => u.uname == uname && u.password == encryptedPwd);
                    if (myUser != null)
                    {
                        List<long> roles = (List<long>)usersRoleDBObj.tbl_users_roles.Where(r => r.user_id == myUser.id).Select(r => r.role_id).ToList();
                        List<string> roles_funtionalities = new List<string>();
                        foreach (var roleId in roles)
                        {
                            List<string> roles_func = rolesFunDBObj.tbl_roles_functionality.Where(x => x.role_id == roleId).Select(x => x.functionality_id).ToList();
                            foreach (string item in roles_func)
                            {
                                Debug.WriteLine(item.ToString());
                                if (!roles_funtionalities.Contains(item))
                                    roles_funtionalities.Add(item.ToString());
                            }

                        }
                        log.Info("roles_funtionalities.Count :" + roles_funtionalities.Count);
                        foreach (string item in roles_funtionalities)
                        {
                            log.Info(item.ToString());
                        }
                        TempData["userFunctionalities"] = roles_funtionalities;
                        TempData["uname"] = myUser.uname;
                        TempData["uId"] = myUser.id;
                        log.Info("User LoggedIn Successfully..!");
                        return RedirectToAction("userHome", "Home");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        TempData["errorMsg"] = "Username or password incorrect..!";
                        log.Info("Username or password incorrect..!");
                        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                    }
                }        
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                log.Error("Exception inside Login () :" + e.StackTrace);
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
```

Comment: Why do you do so in the first place? There's no need to regenerate the edmx files or the source code.

Comment: Database connection does not happens then...!

Comment: Changing the connection string doesn't require rebuilding anything, you can even do it at runtime. You can change the `.config` file to point to the new database, either during development or during deployment. If you have a problem with connectivity *ask about that problem*, don't assume you need to rebuild everything

Comment: I tried it but did not worked..it gives me same error above..

Comment: Post the code that connects to the database and the full exception as returned by `Exception.ToString()`

Comment: A lot of people are using EF for a lot of years. If there was such a problem it would have been discovered a decade ago. The only thing that needs to change during deployment is the connection string. Post the actual code, actual exception. Or read the documentation that explains how to write connection strings

Comment: Okay I have posted code as well as exception. thanks

Comment: That's not the *exception*, that's only part of the call stack. It could be a login failure because the *insecure* password doesn't match

Comment: " its not allowing db connection " Exception inside Login () :   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.OpenStoreConnectionIf(Boolean openCondition, DbConnection storeConnectionToOpen, DbConnection originalConnection, String exceptionCode, String attemptedOperation, Boolean& closeStoreConnectionOnFailure)

Comment: BTW there's absolutely no reason to roll your own authentication, it can only lead to security breaches. ASP.NET already provides its own strong authentication mechanism with secure password storage. Does `PasswordUtils.Encrypt` use 1000 iterations of SHA256 hashing on the salted password? If not, if it tries to *encrypt* the password, it's as good as broken. There's a reason passwords are never encrypted, never sent to customers if forgotten.

Comment: No its just doing MD5 Encryption. Do I need to do any changes in .edmx file ? it not doing connection with database at all